# How can I target text when there is no next sibling?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape dynamically generated pages with BeautifulSoup, sometimes I get loose text and somethings I don't.

How can I extract the loose text below, I tried to use next sibling but the text is not contained in any tags.

```
<div class="div1">

<table class="table1"></table>
<ul></ul>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might do is use a css selector with [select](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) `div.div1 ul` and match the [next_sibling](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling)

```
html_doc = """
<div class="div1">

<table class="table1"></table>
<ul></ul>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt

</div>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
result_page = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

for text in result_page.select("div.div1 ul"):
    print(text.next_sibling.strip())
```